# Convert pandas df column containing datetime values from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +5.30 to result value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timezone

have this dataframe column containing datetime values

```
date
2024-02-21 19:52:22+05:30
2024-02-21 19:29:14+05:30
2024-02-21 19:06:18+05:30
```

how to convert the column to get result values instead of +5.30

```
date
2024-02-22 01:22:22
2024-02-22 00:59:14
2024-02-22 00:36:18
```

Comment: an offset of +5:30 h from UTC in `2024-02-21 19:52:22+05:30` means that UTC is `2024-02-21 14:22:22+00:00`, not `2024-02-22 01:22:22`. Offsets as specified by ISO8601 are time periods East of Greenwich, not West.

Answer (score 1):

since I couldn't find a concise answer here on SO (i.e. a duplicate of the question), here's how you would convert string input with UTC offset specification to a datetime series, convert to UTC and remove the time zone information. Note that the last step is optional; you might consider keeping the tz information.

```py
# dummy data:
df
                        date
0  2024-02-21T19:52:22+05:30

# convert string to datetime in UTC, then remove tz info,
# could also set `format="ISO8601"` here, if using pandas v2
df["date_utc"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], utc=True).dt.tz_localize(None)

# gives
df
                        date            date_utc
0  2024-02-21T19:52:22+05:30 2024-02-21 14:22:22
```